# Install .NET app developed with VS2012 on Windows 98

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-98

Can I install .Net app developed in Visual Studio 2012 in Windows 98???

I am using .NET framework 4.5.1 and i have developed desktop application in Windows 7 Ultimate
I have to install this app in different PCs but one of them has win-98 so I need to know whether i install it same way as i did for other PCs or i have to do something else.

Because formatting OS is last option as there are some important programs working perfectly on Win-98 and can't afford to lost old things for just one app.

I have installed in Windows 07 as well as in Xp but don't know whether it'll work properly in `Win98` or Not.

Is there any Solution if your answer is No. ?

Comment: .Net 2.0 was the last version that had partial support for '98.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[According to Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229070%28VS.80%29.aspx), Windows 98 supports .NET 2.0 based apps.

So technically it should be possible for you to deploy one you made with VS2012, if you set the target framework option at 2.0 in the project build options.

**BE CAREFUL:** this does *not* guarantee that the exact same code that runs on other windows versions will work exactly the same in Win98. There could be very subtle variations if for example you are using COM interopt, P/Invoke calls or if you're using a 3rd party control library.

Also, be aware that targeting 2.0 takes away many great things that came with .NET over the years, such as LINQ, Xaml and async/await.

If I may suggest (please note that I don't know what your requirements are), rather than trying to directly support a 16 years old OS, why don't you develop a web front with an ASP.NET backend instead? This will allow you to remain up to date with .NET goodness and reuse any business logic code you may already have.

Comment: I would recommend upgrading the OS on this machine to "Windows Fundamentals for Legacy PCs" (WinFLP) - a little-known XP derivative intended to run on Win98-era hardware. There are tools for allowing modern software to run on Win98 such as KernelEx, but I don't believe there's currently any way to run a newer version of the .NET framework than 2.0. I realize this is an old question, but the info is still relevant if someone has a similar question. As Crono said, a web UI is a good alternative (and using KernelEx you can run a relatively modern browser on 98 with little difficulty).

Answer (score 0):

According to the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298569/is-the-net-framework-usable-on-win98) it might work if you set the target platform as .NET 2.0.